# difference between django.contrib.syndication.feeds.Feed and django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed?

Tags: python, django, rss

I'm creating a new feed from [**django.contrib.gis.feeds.Feed**](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/gis/feeds.py) which inherits [**django.contrib.syndication.feeds.Feed**](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/syndication/feeds.py). I notice that when I try to initialize a Feed from gis, that it requires 3 arguments (self, slug, request), but when I try to initialize a Feed from [**django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed**](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/syndication/views.py), I don't need to do that. I'm just confused why it is necessary to have two different Feed classes. Thanks! (BTW I'm running Django 1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django.contrib.syndication.feeds.Feed is a deprecated class which, if I understand correctly, is now just a wrapper around the view-based API for backwards compatibility. You should use django.contrib.syndication.views.Feed so that you don't lose support in a future version. However, in terms of the gis feed, if you don't want to write your own module then you're probably stuck having it inherit the deprecated class for now, knowing that it will probably be changing soon.